# "End-of-central-directory signature not found" when unzipping

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, unzip

When I unzip the file by double click I get the error

```
2:no such file or directory
```

After that I open terminal and use the below command but I get the below result:

```
unzip /Users/mahesh/Desktop/maheshapp.zip 
Archive:  /Users/mahesh/Desktop/maheshapp.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /Users/mahesh/Desktop/maheshapp.zip or
        /Users/mahesh/Desktop/maheshapp.zip.zip, and cannot find /Users/mahesh/Desktop/maheshapp.zip.ZIP
```

Answer (score 7):

Try below command on terminal.

> ditto -x -k source.zip Destination_Dir

**ditto** will recover most of the contents. Credit goes to http://ask.metafilter.com/157754/Mac-OS-X-Recovering-a-corrupted-zip-file

Comment: What's the difference between `ditto` and `zip`?

Comment: @Pacerier ditto: copy directory hierarchies, create and extract archives and zip: package and compress (archive) files

Answer (score 1):

you have splitted binaries, like file.zip.001, file.zip.002 ... you may just need to combine the files e.g. using cat command: cat file.zip.* > single.zip

Credits: https://superuser.com/questions/365643/how-to-unzip-split-files-on-os-x/1067907?newreg=5fb5d89c2d2a4ae5aeb1842dd233b8d1

Answer (score 0):

I had this error message and the only solution for me was to install the trial of WinRAR and use that.  The zip file wouldn't extract using either the built-in Windows 10 or MacOS extraction utilities.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when my linux run out of space:

```
    [root@client actimize429]# unzip ais-linux-setup-4.29.0.9-20200616.090151-1.zip
Archive:  ais-linux-setup-4.29.0.9-20200616.090151-1.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of ais-linux-setup-4.29.0.9-20200616.090151-1.zip or
        ais-linux-setup-4.29.0.9-20200616.090151-1.zip.zip, and cannot find ais-linux-setup-4.29.0.9-20200616.090151-1.zip.ZIP, period.
```